# How to display the text of an html file in UIAlertView as a message

Tags: iphone, html, uialertview

i am new to iPhone programming.. 
i have an html file..in that 3 lines of text is there.
i want to display that text in alertview in the message part.
for this we need to read the html and store the data in a string..Den use that sting as a message...
am i right..?
then hw to read the html and how to store that in a string..?

please help me out

Thank u
......

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:chapter.page  ofType:@"html"];
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];

```
    UIAlertView *tAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:content delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"CLICK HERE", @"OR CONTINUE", @"OR BACK",nil];


    tAlert.tag=TOSChapter;

    [tAlert show];

    [tAlert release];
```

in this its displaying all the tags of html...instead of parsing the html is there any other way to display the content of html in alertview..?

Thank u...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the file from your resources:

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfile" ofType:@"html"];    
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: htmlPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Then, parse the HTML for your substrings.

Comment: Thanks Lou Franco..for the quick response...
Shold i parse to get the data in the html...?
cant i add this HTML file ( webView )to the UIAlertView as a subView..?

or is there any other way..?

Thanks again..